# Define a custom delete rule for Parent-Child relationships

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a custom delete rule on a relationship between a parent and a child table. What I'd like to do is to apply cascade delete on the child if the child's column 'IsActive' is set to false and to apply 'NoAction' rule if this column is set to true. How can I do this?

Comment: You could handle this in a trigger, but do you really want to orphan the "active" children when the parent is deleted? Or would the rule be to deny the delete request (which you could handle in an INSTEAD OF trigger) if any children are "active?"

Comment: Yes, I do. Explaining the logic synthetically here, the child row is only important if it is active, otherwise it is still invalid. I don't really "delete" the parent, I only update its IsDeleted column to true. My MVC application handles the rest of the logic. But I need this to work on the sql side because the code that handles the relationship on this MVC application is maintained by someone else who won't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you could write a trigger on your table that would be something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ParentTable_Update
    ON ParentTable
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(IsDeleted) BEGIN
        DELETE FROM ct
            FROM inserted i
                INNER JOIN ChildTable ct
                    ON i.ID = ct.ParentID
                        AND ct.IsActive = 0
            WHERE i.IsDeleted = 1
    END /* IF */
END /* Trigger */
```

Comment: I like your solution.Thanks for your help, Joe.